# while and foreach correct php

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop

Need help to correct code

```
$aaa = do_mysql_query("SELECT num FROM ticketnums WHERE ticketid = '".$coin['ticketid']."' ORDER BY num asc") or sqlerr(__FILE__, __LINE__);
$rows = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($aaa)) {
    $rows[] = $row['num'];
}

$array_numbers = explode("|", $coin['results']); // 31|22|65|9|5|10|55|51|21|63|33|67|4|45|50|19|62
 foreach($array_numbers as $keno_num) {
     foreach ($rows as $r){ // 7, 8 or 9 nums
        if($r == $keno_num){
         echo "<td class=\"table_my_tickets\"><font color=\"red\"><b>".$r."</b></font></td>"; 
       }else{
         echo "<td class=\"table_my_tickets\">".$r."</td>"; 
       }
    }
 }
```

The problem that is print me **numbers results * numbers of tickets**. (number results = 17 numbers) and (number of tickets = 7,8 or 9).

This is needed be 7,8 or 9 numbers and some of them with red color (if number == $keno_num)

Thanks for correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading that right, you only need one loop, not two nested loops. In pseudo-code:

```
foreach($array_numbers as $keno_num) {
   if (in_array($keno_num, $rows)) {
      ... number is on results array, draw red number
   } else {
      ... no match, draw regular number
   }
}
```